# Wait for one of several threads to finish?

Tags: c, pthreads

I am implementing a thread pool. The work required by each thread is 1-10 seconds of CPU, so I'm happy to have a traditional thread pool with workers, or I'm happy to spawn a new thread for each unit of work. It doesn't matter.

I would like to have some way for the master control thread to know when one of the N worker threads finishes its work and is ready for more (or its time to start another). I've looked at pthread_join and pthread_cond_wait. There doesn't seem to be a way to wait for one of N. So I thought about having the master thread have a variable that it uses to go to sleep and having the workers wake it up. This seems to work if the workers don't die. However, if they die, there's a window between the time that the worker wakes up the controller and the time it dies which I don't want to deal with.

I've looked at Intel's TBB but it looks much more complicated than I need.

Is there a simple equivalent in PTHREADS to WaitForMultipleObjects in Microsoft Windows?

Comment: I tagged this as C, please feel free to change it if that is not the case.

Comment: have you tried looping(N) for pthread_join. http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_join.html

Comment: I agree with small_ticket. Why can't looping for n pthread_joins work?

Comment: @small/jay, how does it help to wait until _all_ threads finish? OP wants to know when _any_ of them finish. Starting 10 then waiting for all 10 to finish before starting another won't be very efficient.

Comment: @paxdiablo vy32 wrote "I would like to have some way for the master control thread to know when one of the N worker threads finishes its work and is ready for more (or its time to start another)" and as far as i understand from this, he wants to wait 10 to finish before starting a new one. Am i wrong?

Comment: Well, that would be a strange way to create a multi-consumer setup. In addition, the snippet "There doesn't seem to be a way to wait for one of N" seems to indicate the more conventional model where as soon as a single thread finishes, it's given more work. Still it's open to interpretation and I didn't write the question so I'm not going to demand you accept my point of view :-)

Comment: The problem with looping(N) is that you are polling all 10 of the threads, which means that you are spinning. I would like to avoid polling/spinning. I would like the master thread to SLEEP until ANY of the threads are available, so that the thread can be given more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reasonably simple use case for condition variables.

Have an integer count of the number of active work items, mutex protected. In addition, have two condition variables, one for signalling the worker threads that work is available on a queue, the other to signal the main thread that a thread has finished. Something like:

```
main:
    set freethreads to numthreads
    init mutex M, condvars TOMAIN and TOWORKER
    start N worker threads
    while true:
        wait for work item
        claim M
        while freethreads == 0:
            cond-wait TOMAIN, M
        put work item in queue
        decrement freethreads
        cond-signal TOWORKER
        release M

worker:
    init
    while true:
        claim M
        while no work in queue:
            cond-wait TOWORKER, M
        get work to local storage
        release M
        do work
        claim M
        increment freethreads
        cond-signal TOMAIN
        release M
```

Note that the loops run forever. In reality, there would be signals which made them exit and run termination/cleanup code.

Comment: The `cond-signal` should be done *before* releasing the mutex - otherwise, the thread may get signalled in between testing the condition and waiting.

Comment: Yeah, @caf, I realised that as you were writing your comment. Updated to fix.

Comment: Hi. This is very interesting but I think that what you have done is implemented a basic counting semaphore, right?  I like the use of TOMAIN and TOWORKER. The main sleeps until one of the workers send it a message indicating that freethreads has been incremented and multiple workers sleep on cond-wait. This also assumes that there is a queue?  My question --- did you actually try this? What happens if multiple workers are waiting? I guess that cond-signal assures that only one of them will wake up?

Comment: @vy32, actually, more than one may be woken (that's the nature of condition vars) but only one will grab the mutex first. That's why the worker cond-wait is inside the loop, because two may wake up, the first gets the work and the second (when it finally gets the mutex), sees an empty queue and keeps looping.

Comment: @paxdiablo, So M protects queue, TOWORKER, and TOMAIN. That's very nice. The problem with the semaphore solution is that the main thread then needed to figure out which worker actually woke up. That's avoided with this solution. I really like it. Thanks.

Comment: @vy32, it's probably best to ask another question, giving the code that you have, and providing a link to this one for reference. You're more likely to get a better cross section of answers with a new question.

Comment: I found the bug. Somewhere unrelated. Tracing multi-threaded programs is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using a counting semaphore?

Comment: Yeah semaphores are the standard solution for this type of thing.

Comment: The standard 1990s solution. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of architecturing, it'd be the responsibility of the thread pool. Synchronization between the workers and the pool should be exists.

pthread_mutex_lock() or counting semaphore (sem_wait() and sem_post() ) is good for such synchronization. One way to do that can be illustrated as:

1. the pool init's the counting semaphore by calling: sem_init(p_to_sem_t, 0, int n);
2. n workers acquire the semaphore by calling: sem_wait();
3. the pool waits for the workers to come back by calling: sem_wait();
4. the pool checks the semaphore count to see if all workers are parked.
5. worker(s) release their lock when they're exiting by calling: sem_post();

Comment: If you're gonna wait for one of multiple workers to join back, step-4 SHOULD be removed from the procedure.

Comment: This seems very simple and elegant. I honestly didn't know about the <sepmaphore.h> file --- I was just looking in <pthread.h>. Is there an easy way to know *which* of the workers finished, or do I need to maintain a separate array that keeps track of that?

Comment: On second reflection, the problem with this approach is that the main thread then needs to figure out which one woke up to give it work...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, POSIX semaphores are much less widely supported than threads. And the conditional variable approach is much nicer.

Comment: @vy32, one question, are your workers proactive? if so, I recommend you integrate work queue into your pool so that each worker can get the work from the pool aggressively. If you still need a way to know which workers are parked back, as my understanding, array and ID should be used.