# C++ Waiting for one of several threads to finish and get that threads return value

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to parallelize the execution of a randomized algorithm in the following way: I have a number of threads which execute the same randomized operations in a loop and return in case of success. I want to start multiple threads and return once at least one of them stops (returns a value). As a minimum example, consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <future>
#include <vector>

int random_algorithm(){
    while(true) {
        int random_number = rand() % 10 + 1;
        if (random_number > 5){
            return random_number;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::future<int>> thread_vec;
    for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
        std::future<int> t = std::async(std::launch::async, random_algorithm);
        thread_vec.push_back(std::move(t));
    }
    **//Instead of the following loop, I want to**
    **//continue execution as soon as one of the threads returned.**
    for(auto& th: thread_vec){ 
        th.wait();
        std::cout << "thread returned " << th.get() << std::endl;    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, instead of calling `th.wait()` on every thread, I just want to wait here until one of the threads in `thread_vec` has finished its work and then get that threads return value. How would I achieve this?

Note: I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264460/wait-for-one-of-several-threads-to-finish) question, but this does not seem to reveal which of the threads finished its work.

Comment: Use a queue.  Threads all push their results to the queue, the main thread blocks waiting to pop the first result off the queue.

Comment: @AndrewHenle that works, but it's kind of sad to use a queue as a condition variable alone.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Why sad? In software design (and in electronics design) if a library/module/class/function/component/etc. does what you need, and it also does fifteen other things that you don't need, then it does what you need. And, if it doesn't cost too much (memory, power, board space, CPU cycles, $$) to use it, then it doesn't cost too much to use it. If it does what you need, and it doesn't cost too much, then.. _use it!!!_

Comment: @SolomonSlow not that I disagree, it's just that I wanted to raise that it might be a good idea to understand *why* the queue works, and what it does internally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start discussing your code:

`rand()` is **not** re-entrant safe. **You must never use it in multiple threads concurrently**. Also, it's typically a **really** bad random number generator.

You're using C++11 or later, so use `std::random` instead.

---

Solving your problem: instead of waiting on a future, you should simply share a condition variable with all threads, and the first thread to notify the variable and thus the main thread ends the computation.

Result returning can be implemented through atomic variables, for example (`std::atomic`).